# Skip first row when rendering table data with Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a list representing rows of data. The first item in the list is the column names. When I render the rows using Jinja, I don't want to render the column names, because generating a url for that makes no sense. How can I skip the first row while rendering?

```
array = [
    ['one','two','three'],        
    [0,12,13],
    [1,22,16],
    [5,66,21],
    [2,55,44]
]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html', table=array)
```

```html
{% for item in table %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ item[0] }}</a></td>
    <td><a href="{{ url_for('customer', item[1]) }}">{{ item[1] }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ item[2] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is for the template to skip the 1st entry in the array, simply pass to it the appropriate slice of your array, i.e.:

```
return render_template('test.html', table=array[1:])
```